# Como deixar componentes responsivos em varios tamanho de tela

Tags: android

Olá, queria saber como deixar os componentes responsivo para diversos tamanhos de tela, ex:
tenho uma imageview porem ela fica um tamanho no tablet, e o mesmo tamanho em um celular pequeno, ou seja no celular pequeno vai ficar grande.
Queria saber como reajustar esse tamanho que fique um padrao em todos os aparelhos.

xml do que quero deixar responsivo:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight ="3"

    android:src="@drawable/splashhhh2" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso você pode utilizar os arquivos dimens.xml nas pastas values.

Por exemplo, você tem um ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/imageview_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
/>
```

Assim, na pasta values-mdpi, por exemplo, você cria o arquivo dimens.xml e coloca:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="imageview_width">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="imageview_height">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Depois você cria na pasta values-xlarge, o mesmo arquivo, mas coloca outros valores:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="imageview_width">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="imageview_height">60dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Você pode criar os arquivos dimens em varias combinações de pasta, por exemplo values-normal-hdpi.

Outra opção seria utilizar o campo peso do componente LinearLayout. Por exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Assim os componentes vão ocupar sempre as mesmas porcentagens da tela, independente do seu tamanho.

Comment: Como funciona esse peso? porque 10 no primeiro? 3 no segundo, e 7 no terceiro?

Comment: São apenas valores de exemplo. Você define no LinearLayout qual vai ser o seu tamanho máximo. E depois divide o peso nos filhos dele. @WarLock

Comment: Eu fiz as alterações no xml, e não vi mudanças, o que pode ser?

Comment: Qual dos dois jeitos você fez? @WarLock

Comment: o segundo, por parecer mais simples

Comment: coloque o código do layout por favor

Comment: Postei o código, ja tentei diversos valores mas não muda nada.

Comment: Você precisa colocar o width como 0 dp

Comment: Se colocar 0 da erro: Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible

Comment: Você colocou no "pai" do seu ImageView android:weightSum?

Comment: Coloquei do jeito que vc colocou la no LinearLayout android:weightSum="10"

Comment: coloque o bloco inteiro do layout entao por favor

Comment: Não consigo postar todo o codigo, so aparece a parte da imageview, segue no pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ZRJ7VsyT

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16262/discussion-between-war-lock-and-helder).

Answer (score 0):

Para tornar o seu layout responsivo voce tera de criar diferentes resources para as diferentes configuracoes que voce quiser.
Voce pode criar as pastas dentro da pasta res seguindo os seguintes qualificadores(Os mais comuns):

- **Menor largura(Smallest Width)**: o android usa o menor valor da tela entre a altura e a largura para definir os recursos que vai utilizar. nome da pasta : layout-swdp onde o N e  dimensão a em dp. Exemplo: layout-sw320dp, layout-sw720dp.
- **Largura disponível**: Igual ao qualificador anterior, mas este verifica apenas o valor da largura do dispositivo. nome da pasta: layout-wdp onde o N e o valor da largura largura. Exemplo: layout-w320dp
- **Altura disponivel**: Qualificador semelhante ao anterior, so que ao inves da largura do dispositivo toma em conta a altura. nome da pasta: layout-hdp. Exemplo: layout-h720dp
- **Tamanho da tela**: utilizando este qualificador, o android verifica o tamanho da tela e esta pode ser *small- aproximadamente 320x426dp*, *normal-aproximadamente 320x470dp*, *large-aproximadamente 480x640dp*, *xlarge-aproximadamente 720x960dp*.Exemplo: layout-normal
- **Orientação dos dispositivos**: Este qualificador seleciona a pasta com os recursos necessários de acordo com a orientação do dispositivo. *port- portrait* e *land-landscape*. Exemplo: layout-land.
- **Densidade de pixeld da tela(dpi)**: este qualificaodr seleciona a pasta com os recursos certos apos identificara densidade de pixels da tela. estas densidades podem ser : *ldpi-Low density-120dpi*, *mdpi-medium density-160dpi* *hdpi-high densitiy-240dpi*, *xhdpi- extra high density-320dpi*.

Após escolher qual dos qualificadores melhor ira descrever como voce quer definir as telas que vai suportar voce devera criar pastas de *values* utilizando os qualificadores acima e colocar em cada uma dela o ficheiro dimens.xml com as dimensoes que voce vai utilizar dentro dos ficheiros de layout  para definir o *width* e o *height*.